# How to Make CSV Format Report of User Information using Active Scaffold in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: activescaffold

I am New Ruby on Rails. I want to export CSV File for User Information which is having user controller.

Ruby version: 1.8.7
Rails version: 2.3.8

Example:

I have user controller:

```
    class Admin::UserController < ApplicationController
          active_scaffold :users do |config|
                 config.list.sorting = {:name => :asc}

                 config.columns[:name].form_ui=:text_input
                 config.columns[:name].inplace_edit=true

                 config.columns[:email].form_ui=:text_input
                 config.columns[:email].inplace_edit=true

                 config.columns[:phone].form_ui=:text_input
                 config.columns[:phone].inplace_edi=true

          end
    end
```

Model: user

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

I want to export file as CSV the above details which having my user controller. is this any requirement for doing this? please anybody can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the ActiveScaffold Export plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/activescaffoldexport/wiki/Features

https://github.com/ewildgoose/active_scaffold_export